# SQL Server Synonyms and Concurrency Safety With Dynamic Table Names

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, concurrency, transactions

I am working with some commercial schemas, which have a a set of similar tables, which differ only in language name e.g.:

```
Products_en
Products_fr
Products_de
```

I also have several stored procedures which I am using to access these to perform some administrative functions, and I have opted to use synonyms since there is a lot of code, and writing everything as dynamic SQL is just painful:

```
declare @lang varchar(50) = 'en'

if object_id('dbo.ProductsTable', 'sn') is not null drop synonym dbo.ProductsTable
exec('create synonym dbo.ProductsTable for dbo.Products_' + @lang)

/* Call the synonym table */
select top 10 * from dbo.ProductsTable
update ProductsTable set a = 'b'
```

My question is how does SQL Server treat synonyms when it comes to concurrent access? My fear is that a procedure could start, then a second come along and change the table the synonym points to halfway through causing major issues. I could wrap everything in a `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN` which should theoretically remove the risk of two processes changing a synonym, however the documentation is scarce on this matter and I can not get a definitive answer.

Just to note, although this system is concurrent, it is not high traffic, so the performance hits of using synonyms/transactions are not really an issue here.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "commercial schemas"? Does that mean you can't modify the DB schema itself (i.e. only add to it)?

Comment: They are part of a commercial product (Microsoft Commerce Server), so yes I can add to them, but I can't change the conventions or other things which the API would rely on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fear is correct.  Synonyms are not intended to used in this way.  Wrapping it is a transaction (not sure what isolation level would be required) might solve the issue, but only by making the system single user.

If I was dealing with this then I would probably have gone with dynamic SQL becuase I am familiar with it.  However, having thought about it I wonder if schemas could solve your problem.
If you created schema for each language and then had a table called products in each schema.  Your stored proc can then reference an un-qualified table name and SQL should resolve the reference to the table that is in the default schema of the current user.  You'll then need to either change what account your application authenticates as to determine which schema it uses or use EXECUTE AS in a stored proc to decide which schema is default.
I haven't tested this schema idea, I may not have thought of everything and I don't know enough about your application to know if it is actually workable in your case.  Let us know if you decide to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too normally use dynamic SQL, however there is a lot of SQL and I want to make sure it it maintainable rather than just nvarchar strings everywhere and given it isn't performance critical I will look at the transaction route. Your suggestion of schemas is a really interesting one, however I would need quite a bit of time to look into this -- but it's certainly something I will try the next time this problem comes up!